# SMTP OnPremise Relay connector Office 365

Tags: smtp, office365, azure-web-app-service, office365connectors

I've an app which I want it to send emails.

In Office 365, I created the user and is allowed to login: myWebsiteEmail@myDomain.com.

No license is granted to it as I just want it to send emails and won't receive any.

When I try to configure a SMTP OnPremise Relay Connector as shown in this video:
[How to Build an SMTP Relay Connector in Office 365](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how%20to%20setup%20noreply%20mail%20using%20smtp%20office%20365&qpvt=how%20to%20setup%20noreply%20mail%20using%20smtp%20office%20365&view=detail&mid=84E4F3C2D982743EF93384E4F3C2D982743EF933&&FORM=VRDGAR), and using the IP addresses as per this link: [Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) , I get an error saying that the address is invalid?
[image]

And yet, that's what I got from the download:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no such a test environment to do that. But from the linking [video](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how%20to%20setup%20noreply%20mail%20using%20smtp%20office%20365&qpvt=how%20to%20setup%20noreply%20mail%20using%20smtp%20office%20365&view=detail&mid=84E4F3C2D982743EF93384E4F3C2D982743EF933&&FORM=VRDGAR), I could see a note that

> you can also specify CIDR ranges is the format `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/rr`
>   where `rr` is a number from 24 to 32.

Not sure why it is, it seems that you could change to use another IP address mask bit from 24 to 32.

[image]

Comment: You're right. This input box will only validate masks between 24 to 32, despite the fact that EastUS Azure servers use a mask of 20 and 21 in addition to the 24-32. I wonder why's the difference. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: not sure, you may check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/configure-the-connection-filter-policy#use-the-eac-to-edit-the-default-connection-filter-policy